# Limit on number of visitor to the website

Tags: java, php, jquery, html

I design a website which is i want only people with license can visit them. I want know how can limit each license to number of nodes(number of visitors)
for ex:

a person that have only 2 visitor license can only visit the website with two different ips but should not able to visit the website on third or rest ip until he get of the other computer. Also doesn't matter how many user name they have in system.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming you have a database that keeps track of how many "licences" a person currently owns, you can convert these licence data from your database into an IP whitelist. For ex, if a user may log into a control panel, from it, they can register their IP address and use up a licence. They have one less licence and the database will whitelist this IP so that it may access the rest of the site without authentication. In regards to this idea, I personally think it's silly, simply because many of us use dynamic IP addresses and this wouldn't work. You can always do rate limiting of IP addresses. :)

Comment: Thank you for your respond, my problem is dynamic ip addresses. Also i am using this website on lan not on wan (locally on xampp ) like software

Comment: I'm thinking that authentication by IP is not what you want. If you want to have a 1 IP 1 service setup because of rate limiting, that's not the way to go. Even though it's on LAN, I don't believe it changes any information that is exposed to PHP or JavaScript (maybe activeX in IE?). Maybe you could have it lock the user's IP, in that, they may only use the service with a certain IP for a minimum amount of time, after that timeout, they can use a different IP address. So for example, if I used the server's service with `192.168.0.103`, I'd have to wait 1 hour before I could use a different IP.

Comment: thanks for your respond, lets have simple example: we have 2 license : mean only two people concurrently can use this website at time.so user one go on his computer access the website with ip address of 192.168.1.5 and second user go access this from another computer with ip address of 192.168.1.6 , and third user try to connect using his up 192.168.1.7 should get block, but as soon as user 1 or 2 log off he should be able to login to system.

Comment: my last solution was create variable= 2  every time a person login we add to a variable and we check the variable every time to make sure it doesnt read two and if they log off we subtract from the number do you think this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can you a pub-sub architecture to handle your scenario. [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) is one of best open source product that can be used for this type of scenarios.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you haven't explained *how* a pub-sub architecture is even appropriate here, let alone how this particular tool will solve the problem. It sounds to me kind of like you're just trying to promote this tool, which is not appropriate here.

Comment: Please goes through their documentation. They have good samples too. http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Managing+API+Usage

Comment: It's still not at all clear how this is supposed to apply to the question. Amir has said that he is trying to limit access to a **web site**, not an API.